# Quickest way to backup and restore a web application content database across farms?

Tags: deployment, restore

When I perform a complete backup of my development content database using Backup-SPSite and restore the site on a separate farm using Restore-SPSite its currently taking around 25 mins to backup and 45 minutes to restore. Although the process works correctly I'm keen to reduce the time taken as the current deployment time window is an hour turnaround.

I tried exporting only the elements that required deployment but between missing dependencies, missing permissions and also the general lack of SharePoint experience within the organisation I'd feel more comfortable knowing a full backup / restore has been performed.

I believe the reason for the slow backup / restore is due to a single list in the site which contains 9000 items. Each with around 5/6 individual item user role permissions. I can't change this design for the moment so I'm forced to find a better deployment approach.

One thing I've started investigating is taking a SQL Server backup of the content database and restoring it on the destination SQL server. Can I simply restore the dev .bak over the live content database? If so, do I need to IISReset to completely clear the previous cache etc? In the past I've relied on the built in stsadm / PowerShell commands and I can't find any in depth articles covering this option.

Any guidance on the best practice for deploying large content SharePoint sites in a timely manner would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Brian.

Comment: ONE hour turnaround for development? That is crazy!

Comment: An hour from dev to live, different farms. Before the large list was introduced it was taking 5 minutes to backup, 5 minutes to restore. :-( . There is quite a few processes running around populating this list at the moment that I can't just change immediately. Essentially I'm looking for a quick backup / restore, perhaps involving SQL Backups. Longer term I'm going to migrate this list into a seperate SQL table and use BCS to interogate it as an external list so that it's no longer stored as content in the site.

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you are doing that requires regularly pushing content databases to production?

Comment: How big is the site collection backup you are creating with Backup-SPSite? My guess is about 5-6 GB. You can't speed this up unless you invest in faster hardware. I have the same question that Dave does -- why are you regularly deploying content using a site collection backup and restore?

Comment: @Shufler, The backup comes out around 1.5GB. There's about 500 MB of documents in the site, I'm guessing the remainder is down to the volume of list items and unique permissions.

Comment: @DaveWise, It's a business intelligence portal for a FTSE 100 company. The portal hosts lots of process documentation, business information but primarily its a platform for hosting SSRS reports and Excel Services / PowerPivot based worksheets. These interact with SSAS cubes that are massive in terms of size and the data they store. The reason for the regular content database deployments is that the cubes / SSRS reports are hosted on different servers for Dev, UAT, PreProd and Live.

Comment: @DaveWise, The portal contains hundreds of pages with SSRS webparts and Excel Workbooks that use data connections hosted on the same site. As the address of the SSRS report urls and the Excel data connection urls are absolute they must be updated to reflect the server they are being hosted on for each environment. I've created a deployment tool that performs a site backup, copies across to a destination server and restores the content database. After the restore is complete it then iterates through the lists in the site and updates items of specific content types and updates the Excel files.

Comment: @DaveWise: Finally, the team that will be supporting the portal have no SharePoint experience. The tool I mentioned will be used as their promotion process. This needs to be able to guarantee that the development portal is replicated out to the intended destination servers and reconfigured automatically.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Content Deployment mechanisms built into SharePoint that do almost this exact thing?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721058.aspx

Comment: @Dave: As I explained in the previous comments, the content contains items that have urls that are absolute. These references must be updated per environment release to be pointed towards the server being deployed to.